# Eclipse kepler hangs showing only the splash screen while starting first time

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I am using kepler to the ubuntu 14.04 first time. While i start the eclipse it shows the splash screen only and hang on it.
How to overcome from this problem?

Comment: environment variables? logs? process acitivity? tried using a virtual mashine with a fresh installation of ubuntu and eclipse? the exact version of eclipse would be fine as well ;)

Comment: Just in case, would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23339116/6309 Also check which Eclipse you have (32/64 bits), on which ubuntu you run (32/64 bits) and with which java you are running it (32/64 bits)

Comment: both are 64 bits and i had also done fresh installation of eclispe and ubuntu a day before

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem with JBoss Developer Studio, also on a "trusty" machine. Only the splash screen appeared, then jbdevstudio exited.

It was solved by calling jbdevstudio with the "-clearPersistedState" parameter.

It should also work with Kepler.